# Vim show line numbers when using Explore

Tags: vim

In VIM, I use `:Explore` or `:Te` to explore and open a new file. It gets a little tedious to scroll up and down using only `J`, `K`, `Ctrl-D` and `Ctrl-U`.

Is there a way to automatically show line numbers when using `:Explore` or `:Te`? This way I can go directly to the line I want with `32G` if, for example, the line number is 32.

I have `set number` stored in my `.vimrc`, but this does not seem to apply to the file exporer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nu nowrap ro nobl'
```

The settings beside 'nu' are the default settings, I'm not sure if you can enable just `nu` without overriding the rest.

See also [:help netrw](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html).

Comment: Working, thanks! Will accept in 3 minutes when SO allows me to.

Comment: This then goes to jumble up how one navigates `Explore`

Comment: If you are not sure what `g:netrw_bufsettings`'s default setting is, try use the `:echo g:netrw_bufsettings` to get it.